# how to set DIV position to 200 pixels to left of the center

Tags: css, positioning, center

I want to position a `DIV` 200 pixels to left of the center.

I am currently using the following code, but on higher resolution displays (e.g. 1920×1080), the `DIV` was slipping out of position:

```
.hsonuc {
    position: absolute;  
    top: 20px; 
    margin:auto;
    margin-left:200px;
    display:none;
}
```

### What I want to achieve:

[image: Illustrating a div that is positioned 200px to the left of the center of the page]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply position it `50%` from the right (`right:50%;`), and then push it over using `margin-right:200px;` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Beaga/)).

### HTML

```
<div class="hsonuc">DIV</div>
```

### CSS

```css
.hsonuc {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:50%; /* Positions 50% from right (right edge will be at center) */
    margin-right:200px; /* Positions 200px to the left of center */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use combination of % and px;
If your div width is 300px, than half of the div is 150px.  150 + 200 = 350px;
 then use this

```
margin-left:calc(50% - 350px);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Javascript to determine how many pixels from the lefthand side of the browser 200px from the center actually is. That way you don't have to use `position: absolute`.

example (jQuery):

```
var centerMark = Math.round( $(window).width() / 2 ); //define the center of the screen
var elementWidth = $('.hsonuc').width();
var position = centerMark - 200 - elementWidth; //define where 200 left of the center is and subtract the width of the element.

//now you have `position` you can use it almost any way you like.
//I prefer to use margins, but that's all up to you.

$('.hsonuc').css('margin-left', position);
```

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect. This would position the *left* edge of the element 200px left of center, rather than the *right* edge of the element. In addition, you would have to calculate the size of the element and subtract that from `position`.

Comment: @bfrohs You're right. I misread the question. I'm about the edit my answer.